# Laravel Queue Mail files

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5.1

I have been trying to move from directly sending emails, to adding them to Laravel `Queue`, and I've noticed that if the email contains any files, it does not really like to deal with it.

For example, this example works fine if I was to send the email directly, but it will not if I want to add it to the `Queue` because it will not serialise the `$file` variable.

```
$this->mail->queue('emails.contact-us',compact('data'), function($message) use($files)
    {
        $message->from('email@mail.co.uk', 'Test Subject');
            foreach($files as $file){
                $message->attach($file->getRealPath(),array(
                        'as' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
                        'mime' => $file->getMimeType()
                ));
            }
    });
```

If I tried to `getFileContents`, store all data to a varaible and pass the variable to the `Queue`, it will create a `Job`, however instead of the `Json` payload data that it should produce, it adds `0` to the `payload` column.

So my question is, has anybody dealt with this situation before? I have thought about adding file temporary, but it does not seem like a good solution.

Comment: is this happen with small files too?

Comment: @SupunFictionPraneeth this has been tested on ~200kb image

Answer (score 4):

You can use attachData, just pass the file data and the name into it

```
$message->attachData($data, $name, array $options = []);
```

Go take a look at this for more in depth info : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sending-email-with-a-pdf-attachment

**EDIT:** Try a Base64 encoding

```
$this->fileContents = base64_encode(File::get($this->file));
$this->attachData(base64_decode($this->fileContents), 'file.pdf');
```

Comment: I thought so too, but this methods brings me to issue number two, which payload data inside the job table gets stored as `0` and not `json` object, so when the job needs to be executed, it does not know what to do. I've also tried changing the `column name` from `LONGTEXT` to `BINARY`, but that didnt solve the issue either

Comment: As someone mentionned in the link I gave you : "serialization fails when it gets to the binary file data because that data contains invalid UTF-8 characters. base64 encoding the data ensures that the file only contains valid characters before it's serialized".

Comment: This base64_decode file is working in job "__construct" as file content but not working in "handle()". In handle(), I got this base64_decode file as string.
How can i get file in queue job without save any place.